# Problem at taking trace through linux command

Tags: linux, wireshark, trace

I need your assistance for the below issue:

I use the following Linux command to take a trace:

```
sudo tcpdump -i any host IP -w file_name.cap
```

when I open the generated file using wireshark and click on (follow tcp stram), it's no any shown content as per the following screenshot:

[image: follow TCP Stream]

so please advise me if the problem in the command or in the packets..

Many thanks..

**Warda Jouria**

Comment: Is that ip actually set on your interface? Do you see it in `ip addr` output?

Comment: yes it's found, and when I call the url , I get response.  but in the trace packet , I can't find any content..